# How do I return multiple columns of data using ImportXML in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using `ImportXML` in a Google Spreadsheet to access the [`user_timeline` method in the Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses-user_timeline). I'd like to extract the `created_at` and `text` fields from the response and create a two-column display of the results.

Currently I'm doing this by calling the API twice, with

```
=ImportXML("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/matthewsim.xml?count=200","/statuses/status/created_at")
```

in the cell at the top of one column, and

```
=ImportXML("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/matthewsim.xml?count=200","/statuses/status/text")
```

in another.

Is there a way for me to create this display with a single call?

Comment: The user_timeline and method in the Twitter API links return "Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just concatenate your queries with "|"

> ```
> =ImportXML("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/matthewsim.xml?count=200","/statuses/status/created_at | /statuses/status/text")
> ```

Comment: This works pretty well.  I need to follow up with some code to separate the list into two columns with `=INDIRECT((ADDRESS((ROW()-1)*2+1;1)))` or similar.

Comment: @MatthewSimoneau - Rather than try to wedge the columnization into a comment I've added an additional answer (though perhaps I should have edited David's existing one -- not sure).

Comment: Are you getting the results into two columns, or have them in one column in consequent rows?

Answer (score 9):

ImportXML supports using the xpath `|` separator to include as many queries as you like.

```
=ImportXML("http://url"; "//@author | //@catalogid| //@publisherid")
```

However it does *not* expand the results into multiple columns. You get a single column of repeating triplets (or however many attributes you've selected) as shown below in column `A`.

### The following is deprecated

2015.06.16: *`continue` is not available in "the new Google Sheets" (see: The [Google Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093276?hl=en) for `continue`).*

However you don't need to use the automatically inserted `CONTINUE()` function to place your results.

```
=CONTINUE($A$2, (ROW()-ROW($A$2)+1)*$A$1-B$1, 1)
```

Placed in `B2` that should cleanly fill down and right to give you sane column data.

[image: example screenshot]

- ImportXML is in `A2`.
- `A3` and below are how the `CONTINUE()` functions are automatically filled in.
- `A1` is the number of attributes.
- `B1:D1` are the attribute index for their columns.

Comment: Nice one but unfortunately `CONTINUE` is no more available in new google sheets

Comment: That's terrible news for me. The [Google Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093276?hl=en) for `continue` notes that it's "not available in the *new Google Sheets*".

However as of this post `continue` continues to work in existing sheets (just verified).

Answer (score 9):

Another way to convert the rows of =CONTINUE() into columns is to use transpose():

```
=transpose(importxml("http://url","//a | //b | //c"))
```

Comment: `transpose` will only convert column-wise to row-wise but it won't help if you want 3-by-N results as was discussed here.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution (NOT MINE) posted in the comments below. To be honest, I'm not sure how it works. Perhaps @Pandora, the original poster, could provide an explanation.

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(hlookup(1,{1;ARRAY},(row(A:A)+1)*2-transpose(sort(row(A1:A2)+0,1,0)))))
```

> This is a very ugly solution and doesn't even explain how it works. At least I couldn't get it to work due to multiple errors, like i.e. to much parameters for IF (because an array is used). A shorter solution can be found here =ArrayFormula(iferror(hlookup(1,{1;ARRAY},(row(A:A)+1)*2-transpose(sort(row(A1:A2)+0,1,0))))) "ARRAY" can be replaced with IMPORTXML-Function. This function can be used for as much XPATHS one wants. – Pandora Mar 7 '19 at 15:51

In particular, it would be good to know how to modify the formula to accommodate more columns.

Answer (score 0):

I posed this question to the Google Support Forum and this is was a solution that worked for me:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR(IF({1,1,0},IF({1,0,0},INT((ROW(A:A)-1)/2),MOD(ROW(A:A)-1,2)),IMPORTXML("http://example.com","//td/a | //td/a/@href"))),"select min(Col3) where Col3 <> '' group by Col1 pivot Col2",0),"offset 1",0))
```

Replace the contents of IMPORTXML with your data and query and see if that works for you. I

Apparently, this attempts to invoke the IMPORTXML function only once. It's a solution for now, at least.

Here's the [full thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/RwU1T3yixxY;context-place=topicsearch/How$20to$20use$20ImportXML$20to$20import$20multiple$20nodes$20in$20separate$20columns$3F).

Comment: This is a very ugly solution and doesn't even explain how it works. At least I couldn't get it to work due to multiple errors, like i.e. to much parameters for IF (because an array is used). A shorter solution can be found [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/3aRhdKC57yI) `=ArrayFormula(iferror(hlookup(1,{1;ARRAY},(row(A:A)+1)*2-transpose(sort(row(A1:A2)+0,1,0)))))` "ARRAY" can be replaced with IMPORTXML-Function. This function can be used for as much XPATHS one wants.