# Trying to pull the Name and/or ID of the code below, but can only pull the Job-Base-Cost

Tags: html, xml, import, google-sheets

Below is the code I have now. It pulls the Job-Base-Cost just fine, however I cannot get it to pull the ID and or Name of the item. Can you help?

[Link](https://api.eve-industry.org/job-base-cost.xml?names=Abaddon,Absolution,Adrestia,Aeon,Amarr%20Shuttle,Anathema,Anshar,Apocalypse,Apocalypse%20Imperial%20Issue,Apocalypse%20Navy%20Issue,Apostle,Apotheosis,Arazu,Arbitrator,Archon,Ares,Ark,Armageddon,Armageddon%20Imperial%20Issue,Armageddon%20Navy%20Issue,Ashimmu,Astarte,Astero,Atron,Augoror,Augoror%20Navy%20Issue,Avatar,Badger,Bantam,Barghest,Basilik,Bellicose,Bestower,Bhaalgorn,Bifrost,Blackbird,Bowhead,Breacher,Broadsword,Brutix,Brutix%20Navy%20Issue,Burst,Bustard,Buzzard,Caedes,Caiman,Caldari%20Navy%20Hookbill,Caldari%20Shuttle,Cambion,Caracal,Caracal%20Navy%20Issue,Catalyst,Celestis,Cerberus,Chameleon,Charon,Cheetah,Chemosh,Chimera,Chremoas,Claw,Claymore,Coercer,Condor,Confessor,Corax,Cormorant,Council%20Diplomatic%20Shuttle,Covetor,Crane,Crow,Crucifier,Crucifier%20Navy%20Issue,Cruor,Crusader,Curse,Cyclone,Cynabal,Dagon,Damavik,Damnation,Daredevil,Deacon,Deimos,Devoter,Dominix,Dominix%20Navy%20Issue,Dragoon,Drake,Drake%20Navy%20Issue,Dramiel,Eagle,Echelon,Echo,Endurance,Enforcer,Enyo,Eos,Epithal,Erebus,Eris,Etana,Executioner,Exeguror,Exeguror%20Navy%20Issue,Falcon,Federation%20Navy%20Comet,Fenrir,Ferox,Fiend,Flycatcher,Freki,Gallente%20Shuttle,Garmur,Gila,Gnosis,Gold%20Magnate,Golem,Griffin,Griffin%20Navy%20Issue,Guardian,Guristas%20Shuttle,Harbinger,Harbinger%20Navy%20Issue,Harpy,Hawk,Hecate,Hel,Helios,Hematos,Heretic,Heron,Hoarder,Hound,Huginn,Hulk,Hurricane,Hurricane%20Fleet%20Issue,Hyena,Hyperion,Ibis,Imicus,Immolator,Imp,Impairor,Impel,Imperial%20Navy%20Slicer,Incursus,Inquisitor,InterBus%20Shuttle,Ishkur,Ishtar,Iteron%20Mark%20V,Jackdaw,Jaguar,Keres,Kestrel,Kirin,Kitsune,Komodo,Kronos,Kryos,Lachesis,Legion,Leopard,Leshak,Leviathan,Lif,Loggerhead,Loki,Machariel,Mackinaw,Maelstrom,Magnate,Magus,Malediction,Malice,Maller,Mammoth,Manticore,Marshal,Mastodon,Maulus,Maulus%20Navy%20Issue,Megathron,Megathron%20Federate%20Issue,Megathron%20Navy%20Issue,Merlin,Miasmos,Miasmos%20Amastris%20Edition,Miasmos%20Quafe%20Ultra%20Edition,Miasmos%20Quafe%20Ultramarine%20Edition,Mimir,Minmatar%20Shuttle,Minokawa,Moa,Molok,Monitor,Moracha,Moros,Muninn,Myrmidon,Naga,Naglfar,Navitas,Nemesis) to the sites XML pull.

```
=importxml("link","//job-base-cost")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Your URL returns XML. XPath of ``//job-base-cost`` retrieves the text values of the tag ``job-base-cost`` as you say. XPath for retrieving ``id`` and ``name`` of the tag ``job-base-cost`` are ``//@id`` and ``//@name``, respectively. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample of one line of the OP's XML file
`<job-base-cost id="24693" name="Abaddon Blueprint">109555912.69</job-base-cost>`

The OP wants to use the `IMPORTXML` function to report the ID and Name as well as the Job Cost from the XML data. Presently, the OP's formula is:
`=importxml("link","//job-base-cost")`

There are two options:
**1 - One long column**
`=importxml("link","//@id | //@name | //job-base-cost")`

Note `//@id` and `//@name` in the xpath query: `//` indicate nodes in the document (at any level, not just the root level) and `@` indicate attributes. The pipe `|` operator indicates **AND**. So the plain english query is to display the id, name and job-base-cost.

**2 - Three columns (table format)**
`={IMPORTXML("link","//@name"),IMPORTXML("link","//job-base-cost"),IMPORTXML("link","//@id")}`

This creates a series that will display the fields in each of three columns.

Note: there is an arrayformula that uses a single importXML function described in [How do I return multiple columns of data using ImportXML in Google Spreadsheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774671/how-do-i-return-multiple-columns-of-data-using-importxml-in-google-spreadsheets). Readers may want to look at whether that option can be implemented.

My thanks to @Tanaike for his comment which spurred me to look at how xpath works.